# Best way to run a function every 60 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I took a basic react class and looking to make some adjustments to it. Currently, the function is run when clicking my button. I'd rather it run automatically every 60 seconds. I've read about the setInterval() function but I'm unsure exactly where it needs to be run.

Do I just use setInterval() within my render() to run myfunction() every 60s? ie, something like:

```
    render(){
     return(
       setInterval(function(){
             myFunction();
       }, 60000);
       //Show updated this.state.price here
     );
    }
```

Or should I be approaching this differently? Can't get it to work, either way. Here is the majority of my code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPrice();
  }

  getPrice() {
    this.setState({ isGettingPrice: true });
    fetch("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          price: json.bpi.USD.rate,
          time: json.time.updated,
          isGettingPrice: false
        });
      });
  }

  onGetPrice() {
    this.getPrice();
  }

  render() {
    console.log("----- RENDER ------");

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onGetPrice} disabled={this.state.isGettingPrice}>
          Get price
        </button>

        <p>
          {this.state.isGettingPrice
            ? "Loading price..."
            : "$" + this.state.price}
        </p>
        <p>{"Updated " + this.state.time}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try and add your `setInterval` function to your `componentDidMount` function. Returning the `setInterval` function in your render doesn't work because it is expecting JSX.

Comment: Thank you - making progress with that method. It's attempting to run based on my interval but it's telling me that "this.getPrice()" is not a function - why is that?

Comment: @mickdeez Because you never told the compiler that getPrice is a function. You didn't declare it correctly. You need to change this line `getPrice() {...}` to `function getPrice(){...}` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put it in render method, follow the example and see if you have other questions.
This is a link to code pen with answers to update every 1000 second.
https://codepen.io/landingheart-the-animator/pen/QWmReJm

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1";
import ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom@17.0.1";

const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setCounter(counter + 1)
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [counter]);
  return(
    <div className="box">
      <h1>The Button has a ref</h1>  
      <p>counter {counter}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: He's using class components, not functional components, though. Your answer is correct but `useEffect` is for functional components, which can't be used in class components, which is what OP is using.

Comment: no point in using a `setInterval` if you `clearInterval` and create a new one on every call. use `const interval = setInterval(setCounter, 1000, v => v+1);` and eliminate the dependency on `[counter]`.